# Is there a tool to split a book saved as a single PDF into one PDF per chapter?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have a few books as PDFs, and I'd like to split them by chapter for easier consumption on a mobile phone.  Is there any tool (or sequence of tools) I can use to easily split the book into different PDF files by chapter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be hard to do automatically, as there is no *standard* chapter label in a PDF file. However, if you do not mind some manual work, write down the pages for each chapter, and use `pdftk` to select the pages and save them into a new pdf file. For example, if chapter 2 is pages 23-45, do

```
pdftk A=input.pdf cat A23-45 output chapter_2.pdf
```

You need to install pdftk first:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

You can also use ghostscript (which comes preinstalled) directly:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=23 -dLastPage=45 -sOutputFile=chapter_2.pdf input.pdf
```

This is quite easy to convert a script that runs things semi-automatically. First, create an input file; on each line, put the desired output pdf file title, the starting page, the ending page -- like that:

```
chapter1 1 23
chapter2 24 56
```

Save this, using a text editor, to file `pdfchaps.in`.

Now, create a script -- save the following to a file called `pdfchaps.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function pdfextr() { 
  echo "Chapter $2"
  pdftk A=$1 cat A$3-$4 output $2.pdf 
}

chapters=$1
pdffile=$2

echo "Splitting pdf file $pdffile by chapters from $chapters"
cat $chapters | while read line ; do  pdfextr $pdffile $line ; done
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x pdfchaps.sh
```

And run it:

```
pdfchaps chaps.in mybook.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

You have many choices for that:

**1. flpsed**

```
 sudo apt-get install flpsed
```

**2. Pdftk**

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

**3. Pdfedit**

```
sudo apt-get install pdfedit
```

**4. Using GIMP**

Install **krita** using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install krita
```

Open the Gimp, and open the PDF document you wish to edit. For multiple page documents, it is easier on your computer to edit them one page at a time. If you choose more than one page, they will open in individual windows.

Make the necessary changes to the document.Save the document as a Gimp XCF file (you'll have to save several different pages if it is a multi-page document). Close the document, then open the resulting image in Krita.

Printing to PDF with Krita Go to File>Print, then choose Print to PDF. In the same dialogue box, choose the destination folder and name of the output document (such as file1.pdf).

**5. PdfMod**

**6. Inkscape**

An Open Source vector graphics editor, with capabilities similar to Illustrator, CorelDraw, or Xara X, using the W3C standard Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) file format.
Inkscape supports many advanced SVG features (markers, clones, alpha blending, etc.) and great care is taken in designing a streamlined interface. It is very easy to edit nodes, perform complex path operations, trace bitmaps and much more. We also aim to maintain a thriving user and developer community by using open, community-oriented development.

Install inkscape in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

**7. PDF-Shuffler**

PDF-Shuffler is a small python-gtk application, which helps the user to merge or split pdf documents and rotate, crop and rearrange their pages using an interactive and intuitive graphical interface. It is a frontend for python-pyPdf.

Comment: `apt-cache search pdfedit` comes up empty for me (Lubuntu 13.04).

Answer (score 2):

I  was looking now for hours for the perfect tool for the same reason and indeed [pdfsam [image: Install pdfsam]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfsam) is the way to go.

The split by chapter worked for me, it was not necessary to select the pages manually, there is a function provided and you can even select the "depth" -- like e.g. on section, or subsection level.

What took me some time to find out: How to give the output files the name of the chapters instead of the regular naming (user defineable prefix + number of starting page + original document name). After hours of searching I found the solution: One can use "complex prefix(es)" as described [here](http://www.pdfsam.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=HowTo:ConsoleComplexPrefixConfigure). This solved all of my problems and should help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try pdfsam (pdf-split-and-merge) but you have to manually select the beginning of each chapter.